# Finding maximum sum of occurrences of one element in two attempts from a list

Tags: python, algorithm, list, permutation

Best explained by example. If a python list is -

```
[[0,1,2,0,4],
 [0,1,2,0,2],
 [1,0,0,0,1],
 [1,0,0,1,0]]
```

I want to select **two sub-lists** which will yield the max sum of occurrences of zeros present - where sum is to be calculated as below

```
SUM = No. of zeros present in the first selected sub-list + No. of zeros present in the second selected sub-list which were not present in the first selected sub-list.
```

In this case, answer is 5. (First or second sub-list and the last sub-list). (Note that the third sub-list is not to be selected because it has zero present in 3rd index which is same as in first/second sub-list we have to select and it will amount to sum as 4 which will not be maximum if we consider the last sub-list)

What kind of algorithm is best suited if we were to apply it on a big input? Is there a better way to do this in better than in N<sup>2</sup> time?

Comment: This looks n^2 to me. You need to compare each list with `(n-1)` other lists. I'd transform each list to look like `[x==0 for x in sublst]` and map XOR over them, summing the result.

Comment: Could you try re-explaining your example. I don't quite follow why the 3rd sub-list fails

Comment: @AdamSmith n! is much much worse than n^2, enumerating the pairs without regard to order is n(n-1) ~ n^2, i.e. the sum of the values below n rather than their product

Comment: @JaredGoguen bleh, it's Monday, thanks for the correction :)

Comment: You say *"with the condition that they are not present at the same location"*. What exactly does that mean? Say the input is `[[0, 1], [0, 0], [3, 4]]`. What would the expected output be? `[0, 0]` combined with any of the other lists because it has the most zeros in different places? Or would `[0, 0]` combined with `[0, 1]` not be a valid output at all, because they share a 0 as the first element? Or *is* `[0, 0]` + `[0, 1]` a valid output, but it only counts as 1 zero?

Comment: @Aran-Fey the best two sublists you would select in your example are: [0, 0] & [3, 4] giving you two zeros without a matching one at the same location in the other.

Comment: @AdamSmith Clarified the question. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I have edited the question clarifying a bit further. I hope this will clear the confusion.

Comment: @Shanks so we're talking `OR` not `XOR`? `([1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1])` scores 5, as does `([1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0])`?

Comment: @Adam Smith Right..yes.

Answer (score 2):

Binary operations are fairly useful for this task:

1. Convert each sublist to a binary number, where a 0 is turned into a 1 bit, and other numbers are turned into a 0 bit.

   For example, `[0,1,2,0,4]` would be turned into `10010`, which is 18.
2. Eliminate duplicate numbers.
3. Combine the remaining numbers pairwise and combine them with a binary OR.
4. Find the number with the most 1 bits.

The code:

```
lists = [[0,1,2,0,4],
         [0,1,2,0,2],
         [1,0,0,0,1],
         [1,0,0,1,0]]

import itertools

def to_binary(lst):
    num = ''.join('1' if n == 0 else '0' for n in lst)
    return int(num, 2)

def count_ones(num):
    return bin(num).count('1')

# Step 1 & 2: Convert to binary and remove duplicates
binary_numbers = {to_binary(lst) for lst in lists}

# Step 3: Create pairs
combinations = itertools.combinations(binary_numbers, 2)

# Step 4 & 5: Compute binary OR and count 1 digits
zeros = (count_ones(a | b) for a, b in combinations)

print(max(zeros))  # output: 5
```

Comment: For what it's worth, there's nothing special about binary operations here. You can convert the non-zeros to ones and just add them base 10 and count the ones. Also both would fail when the arrays start with one or more zeros.

Comment: @Mark_M Addition would produce incorrect results if the two numbers have a 0 in the same location. That's why I use the binary or. But I don't see the problem with leading zeros in the arrays. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: When numbers have zeros in the same spot, they add to zero, which is what we want — not to count zeros in both arrays. So: [1, 0, 1] + [1, 0, 0] would be 201 -- count the ones = 1, which is the right answer.

Comment: @Mark_M That's the answer for `XOR`, not for `OR`. OP seems to want bitwise OR (`([1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0]) = 2`)

Comment: Okay, now I see what's up — I didn't see the OP's edits which clarify this. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The efficiency of the naive algorithm is O(n(n-1)*m) ~ O(n<sup>2</sup>m) where n is the number of lists and m is the length of each list. When n and m are comparable in magnitude, this equates to O(n<sup>3</sup>).

It might be helpful to observe that naive matrix multiplication is also O(n<sup>3</sup>). This might lead us to the following algorithm:

1. Write each list with only 1's and 0's, where a 1 indicates a non-zero entry.
2. Arrange these lists in a matrix A.
3. Compute the product M=AA<sup>T</sup>.
4. Find the minimum element in M; the row and column correspond to the lists which produce the maximize number of non-overlapping zeros.

Here, (3) is the limiting step of the algorithm. Asymptotically, depending on your matrix multiplication algorithm, you can achieve a complexity down to roughly O(n<sup>2.4</sup>).

An example Python implementation would look like:

```
import numpy as np

lists = [[0,1,2,0,4],
         [0,1,2,0,2],
         [1,0,0,0,1],
         [1,0,0,1,0]]

filtered = list(set(tuple(1 if e else 0 for e in sub) for sub in lists))
A = np.mat(filtered)
D = np.einsum('ik,jk->ij', A, A)

indices= np.unravel_index(np.argmin(D), D.shape)

print(f'{indices}: {len(lists[0]) - D[indices]}') # (0, 3): 0
```

Note that this algorithm on it's own has the fundamental inefficiency that it is calculating both the lower-triangular and upper-triangular halves of dot product matrix. However, the numpy speed-up will probably offset this from the combinations approach. See the timing results below:

```
def numpy_approach(lists):
    filtered = list(set(tuple(1 if e else 0 for e in sub) for sub in lists))
    A = np.mat(filtered, dtype=bool).astype(int)
    D = np.einsum('ik,jk->ij', A, A)
    return len(lists[0]) - D.min()

def itertools_approach(lists):
    binary_numbers = {int(''.join('1' if n == 0 else '0' for n in lst), 2) 
        for lst in lists}
    combinations = itertools.combinations(binary_numbers, 2)
    zeros = (bin(a | b).count('1') for a, b in combinations)
    return max(zeros)


from time import time

N = 1000
lists = [[random.randint(0, 5) for _ in range(10)] for _ in range(100)]

for name, function in {
        'numpy approach': numpy_approach, 
        'itertools approach': itertools_approach
        }.items():
    start = time()
    for _ in range(N):
        function(lists)
    print(f'{name}: {time() - start}')

# numpy approach: 0.2698099613189697
# itertools approach: 0.9693171977996826
```

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm should look something like (with Haskell code as example, so as not to make the process trivial for you in Python:

1. turn each sublist into "Is zero" or "Isn't zero"

   ```
   map (map (\x -> if x==0 then 1 else 0)) bigList
   ```
2. Enumerate the list so you can keep indices

   ```
   enumList = zip [0..] bigList
   ```
3. Compare each sublist with its successive sublists

   ```
   myCompare = concat . go
     where
     go []             = []
     go ((ix, xs):xss) = [((ix, iy), zipWith (.|.) xs ys) | (iy, ys) <- xss] : go xss
   ```
4. Calculate your maxes

   ```
   best = maximumBy (compare `on` (sum . snd)) $ myCompare enumList
   ```
5. Pull out the indices

   ```
   result = fst best
   ```